# Secondary mouse click on iOS13.4

Tags: ios, uikit, ios13, ios13.4

Just playing with the new mouse/trackpad support in iOS13.4 and trying to detect both primary and secondary mouse button clicks.

I can detect them (primary OR secondary clicks) by setting the [buttonMaskRequired](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer/3539032-buttonmaskrequired) on a UITapGestureRecognizer to EITHER UIEventButtonMaskPrimary or UIEventButtonMaskSecondary

BUT if I attempt to recognise both (buttonMaskRequired = UIEventButtonMaskPrimary | UIEventButtonMaskSecondary) then the gesture recogniser doesn't fire (for mouse clicks.)

Anyone know if this is an 'oversight' or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You'd probably need two distinct recognizers. If you set the two flags in a single mask, it probably means that both buttons are required to click simultaneously.

Comment: There's `buttonMask` property on `UIGestureRecognizer` that should help determining which mouse button click was used. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/3538974-buttonmask However, in my testing (iPadOS 13.5) the property is always of `rawValue 0` no matter which mouse button you use. Seems like a bug in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since made progress - but it feels real hacky.

Create 2 tap gesture recognisers - one with primary mask set, and the other with secondary mask set. I then kill the secondary gesture in the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: delegate call if the UITouch type is UITouchTypeDirect so as to stop use getting 2 tap events with a finger.

Comment: I've overridden `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch)` but touch's type is always `.direct`, even when using a mouse

Comment: @SteveKuo Does it work in your Mac Catalyst App? ...the UIEventButtonMaskSecondary seems to work only using CTRL+CLICK ... if I change the trackpad settings from Catalina's Settings the Secondary click is not detected through UIEventButtonMaskSecondary